# How do I animate using javascript and qml?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I've searched the internet and I can't find a simple guide how to animate ui objects in Ubuntu SDK.

Can someone please explain the different parts needed and how they work together?

Answer (score 0):

QtQuick offers a rich set of transition and animation libraries that you can find [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-statesanimations-topic.html). It basically involves changing the properties of an object with the specified time interval.

Here is a code sample to animate a rectangular block to move side ways.

```
     Rectangle {
        id: rect
        color: "Green"
        width: units.gu(20)
        height: width
        x: units.gu(0)
        y: units.gu(0)

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: rectAnimation.start()
        }

        NumberAnimation {
            id: rectAnimation
            target: rect
            property: "y"
            from: units.gu(0)
            to: units.gu(20)
            duration: 500
        }
    }
```

You can trigger animations based on various things like object states, behaviour etc...For instance, if you want the rectangle to increase its size in a fluid manner, you would define the following behavior,

```
Behavior on width {
    NumberAnimation { duration: 500 }
}
```

QtQuick is infinitely powerful. I would highly recommend going through the official Qt documentation to find out the different types of animations available and their triggers.

Note: While developing applications for Ubuntu Touch requires the Ubuntu SDK, it is worth knowing that the Ubuntu SDK itself uses Qt and hence you would get more results if you searched for QML solutions rather than Ubuntu SDK solutions in the future.